# Status of jQuery mobile project

Tags: jquery-mobile

Does anybody have any idea on jQuery Mobile project status?
The latest update in their blog, dated Jan 2016 - is already 1 year old (http://blog.jquerymobile.com/2016/01/28/a-long-overdue-status-update/). They talk about incoming version 1.5 - but nothing more happened for a year.

If the project is dead - what do you use instead of jQuery Mobile?

Thank you

Update: I found this page - http://www.gajotres.net/why-jquery-mobile-is-not-relevant-any-more/ - dated Jan 2016, several days before official statement of jQuery Mobile blog. It recommends switching to Angular or ReactJS.

Comment: API documentation for 1.5 is up at http://api.jquerymobile.com/